# Not the same object in two actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I have a Add view which uploads file which is element of `Question` class

```
@model PasmISO.Domain.Question
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Photo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.QuestionRevisions.First().Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionRevisions.First().Content)
        </div>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Ask" />
}
```

I have 2 actions in my controller

First action is when user clicks at Add button and he gets form to upload photo:

```
 public ActionResult Add()
        {
            db.Users.Add(new User() { Avatar = new Avatar() { Link = new Uri("http://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2E") }, CreationDate = DateTime.Now, LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now, LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now });
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Users.Local.First().Questions = new Collection<Question>() { new Question() };

            var question = new Question();
            question.QuestionRevisions = new Collection<QuestionRevision>();
            var questionRevision = new QuestionRevision();
            questionRevision.Tags = new Collection<Tag>();
            question.QuestionRevisions.Add(questionRevision);

            return View(question);
        }
```

and second action which fires when User accepts form:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Question containers, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
```

The problem is tha I see that `Question` hasn't questionrevisions (is null)

Why this object is resetting?

I have a field in Controller:

```
 PasmISOContext db = new PasmISOContext();
```

Here is a class `Question`

public class Question
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionRevision> QuestionRevisions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionVote> Votes { get; set; }

    public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a definition of my context:

```
public class PasmISOContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Avatar> Avatars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QuestionRevision> QuestionRevisions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Achievement> Achievements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QuestionVote> QuestionVotes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the QuestionRevisions doesn't get properly bound is because the corresponding textarea field doesn't have a correct name so that the default model binder could bind it. You may take a look at the [following blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) post explaining what is the correct wire format for collections.

So to fix the problem one possibility is to change the type in your view model from `ICollection<QuestionRevision>` to `IList<QuestionRevision>` so that you have indexer access to elements of the collection and then in the view simply:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.QuestionRevisions[0].Content)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.QuestionRevisions[0].Content)
</div>
```

Now the generated HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">    
    <textarea cols="20" name="QuestionRevisions[0].Content" id="QuestionRevisions_0__Content" rows="2">Some value</textarea>    
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="QuestionRevisions[0].Content" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Notice how the name of the textarea respects the wire format expected by the default model binder to work with collections. Now when you submit the form the `QuestionRevisions` list will be correctly bound and it will contain a single element.